# How to distinguish between live and non-live NodeList collections?

Tags: javascript, dom, collections, nodelist

Both document.getElementsByTagName('div') and document.querySelectorAll('div') return NodeList collection. The only difference is that first method returns live-collection and second one - a static one.

The question is - is there any opportunity to distinguish one object from another only via inspecting these objects (i.e - not trying to add/remove some items to test "liveness")?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `NodeList` interface is agnostic of its dead or live status.

```
interface NodeList {
  Node item(in unsigned long index);
  readonly attribute unsigned long length;
};
```

It only contains a property `length`, and a method `item` so I'm afraid it's currently not possible to determine if an object is live without manipulating the DOM and seeing the effects.

Comment: You're welcome, and a very interesting question. Is there a specific reason why you want to inspect the *liveness* of the object? If the reason is good and solves genuine problems, might as well propose it to the spec authors at w3.

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll` returns a `StaticNodeList`, which by definition is not "live". Regardless of not being able to interrogate `NodeList`, I wonder if it's safe to assume `NodeList`, by convention, is *always* live.

Comment: @Crescent - I didn't find a mention of `StaticNodeList` in [Selectors API level 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-selectors-api2-20100119/) or in [level 1](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/), but it is only mentioned in a [level 1 draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/WD-selectors-api-20060926/).

Comment: @Anurag: you are right. It appeared as late as Dec 07 (http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/WD-selectors-api-20071221/) but it looks like it has been replaced with `NodeList` as the return type.

Comment: Still, the [latest version](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/#queryselectorall) states "The NodeList object returned by the querySelectorAll()  method must be static, not live" - which is strange, since a NodeList is per se defined to be live.

Comment: @Crescent - for example, in WebKit - document.querySelectorAll('div') instanceof NodeList is true, while trying to replace NodeList with StaticNodeList will cause an error - ReferenceError: Can't find variable: StaticNodeList

Comment: @Anurag - well, actually I'have no any practical reason, but I do believe that such basic properties should be possible to inspect

Comment: @shabunc: yeah, that would be evidence of `StaticNodeList` being no more :( Note however that a host environment (eg a browser) is not required (by spec) to expose *any* top-level types within the global scope. Eg it is not required that `NodeList` be a valid name in the browser either!

Answer (score 6):

```
a=document.querySelectorAll('a');
b=document.getElementsByTagName('a');

a.toString() == "[object NodeList]"
b.toString() == "[object HTMLCollection]"
```

(in FF/Chrome)

Comment: this is coincidental, not definitive. `document.getElementsByName('link').toString() == "[object NodeList]"` and it is live